# Strange compile error regarding overload resolution

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, compiler-errors, overload-resolution

This code fragment:

```
namespace ns
{
    struct last;

    struct first
    {
        typedef last next;
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct chain
    {
        chain<typename T::next> next;
    };

    template <>
    struct chain<last>
    {
    };
}

using namespace ns;

template <typename T>
void f(const T& x)          // #1
{
    f(x.next);
}

void f(const chain<last>&)  // #2
{
}

int main()
{
    f(chain<first>());
}
```

gives the following error on Comeau, and a very similiar error on GCC:

```
"ComeauTest.c", line 27: error: class "ns::chain<ns::last>" has no member "next"
    f(x.next);
        ^
          detected during:
            instantiation of "void f(const T &) [with T=ns::chain<ns::last>]"
                      at line 27
            instantiation of "void f(const T &) [with T=ns::chain<ns::first>]"
                      at line 36
```

It does compile, however, if either `#2` is defined ahead of `#1`, or if `last` is declared outside of `ns`.

Any explanation for this?

Answer (score 3):

Case 1)

```
template <typename T>
void f(const T& x)          // #1
{
    f(x.next); //where's f ??
}

void f(const chain<last>&)  // #2
{
}
```

You need to make sure that `#2` is a template specialization of `#1` by specifying `template<>` above `void f(const chain<last>&)  // #2`

Without `template<>` `void f(const chain<last>&)` would be interpreted as an overload of `f`. So a call to `f(x.next);` would be ill formed because of the missing declaration of `void f(const chain<last>&)`.

Adding a declaration of the overload above the function template would make your code compile.

Solutions:

1)

```
template <typename T>
void f(const T& x)          // #1
{
    f(x.next); //hmm specialized version down there.
}

template<>
void f(const chain<last>&)  // #2
{
}
```

2)

```
void f(const chain<last>&); // #0

template <typename T>
void f(const T& x)          // #1
{
    f(x.next); //hmm I can see #0, call #2
}

void f(const chain<last>&)  // #2
{
}
```

---

Case 2)

```
void f(const chain<last>&)  // #2
{
}

template <typename T>
void f(const T& x)          // #1
{
    f(x.next); // found!!
}
```

Comment: But the POI of `#1` is right after `main`, where `#2` is visible.

Comment: My confusion (and maybe uj2's) is that the call to f in main is selecting the templated f rather than the non-templated f. At the call in `main`, both functions are visible, right? Why is this happening?

Comment: @JoshD: There are complicated rules about which overloads are considered. My guess is, informally spoken, if the compiler can decide at the point of definition what to call, then it won't change that decision at the point of instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
template <typename T>
void f(const T& x)          // #1
{
    f(x.next);
}

void f(const chain<last>&)  // #2
{
}
```

... the call to `f` in the body of the first can not ever call the second `f`, because the second `f` is not visible at that point.

So if you get into the first `f`, then it will recurse down to first error. :-) I'm talking about compile time recursion here, as long as `next` is of a type that `f` is not yet instantiated for.

And the call in `main`, ...

```
int main()
{
    f(chain<first>());
}
```

... necessarily calls the first `f`, since `chain<first>` does not match the argument type of the second `f`.

This results in recursive call `f(` arg of type `chain<last>` `)`. And when trying to instantiate `f` for argument type `chain<last>` you get an error, since there's no `next` attribute in `chain<last>`.

Regarding the code apparently compiling OK when placing the declaration of `last` in the global namespace, I don't know. Are you sure? Note: I haven't tried any of this with a real compiler.

Cheers & hth.,